# how to connect centos from windows remotely?

Tags: centos, remote

I am using Oracle virtualbox and I have installed centos 6.4. How can I connect remotely to centos with WinSCP from Windows? There are fields like "hostname" in WinSCP but I don't know what to write.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the SSH service running in CentOS, you can connect to the IP address of your virtual machine (given by `ifconfig` or `ip addr`).

But for VirtualBox, you will probably need/want to set your network interface to "Bridged" in the virtual machine options, that way the VM will get an IP address from your network. (It's possible with NAT mode, but requires more configurations).

Comment: when I write "ip addr" it shows 3-4 different address. Which one do I need to use can you be more specific?

Comment: Try whatever address is assigned to your `eth0` interface. If you set the virtual machine to Bridged mode, this IP will be in the IP range of your network.